# JMeter - Need to submit POST data but I only wish to modify a single field

Tags: jmeter

I'm running some JMeter tests for editing a field. If I use the JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, I can get an accurate representation of the page and edits I made.

It creates a HTTP POST request with a parameter for every field, checkbox and dropdown on the page. I only really care about modifying ONE of them.

My problem is I can't just remove all the other parameters from the POST data because the page interprets this as if I removed all of them from the page (and then complains that there's missing data). So I'm left with trying to obtain the current values for the remaining editable fields and checkboxes so that I can re-submit them when I only want to modify a single field.

For an example, imagine I'm submitting some user data with fields for Name, Email and Address. I want to change the name by adding a 1 to the end of it and leave the other two fields as they are.

My thoughts for accomplishing this:

1) Use XPath to try to get the values shown on the page, store them all in variables and re-submit them in the post request. This is messy and also very difficult as the page is shown in a pop-up window, adding to the complexity of it.

2) Query the database for all the information and re-submit it. Seems like a lot of overhead, plus the data isn't freely available .. I'd rather not have to try to do this.

3) Use some other element of JMeter I'm not aware of to obtain the specific element data from the page. Maybe some listener I haven't figured out yet? If I could pull the parameters from the page and save them, that would be VERY convenient.

4) Somehow submit a POST request with only one field, specifying that I do not wish to clear out the remaining fields, I just want to leave them alone. I will freely admit that I am not super familiar with web applications so there may be a very obvious reason as to why this can't be done (or it's dependent on how its handled by the back-end of the application).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

From the whole post, I understand that you want to parameterise a field, where each time different value will be passed.

If my understanding is correct, the answer lies in [CSV Dataset Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), where you can pass the values from a CSV file.

From your Example:

> For an example, imagine I'm submitting some user data with fields for
>   Name, Email and Address. I want to change the name by adding a 1 to
>   the end of it and leave the other two fields as they are

To achieve this:

Steps to follows:

1. Create a csv file. fill the names as follows:
   `names
   name1
   name2
   name3
   name4`
2. `names` is the column header and remaining are values.
3. Add `CSV Dataset Config` to your Test Plan.
4. Specify the file path.
5. replace the value in the name field in `HTTP Post` request as `${names}`. that's it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the values ahead of time. I need to load the page, obtain all the values that already exist on the page, change one of them, and re-submit them all.

Comment: Then you just correlate the values using 'Regular Expression Extractor' which allows you you to apply regex on the response and catpture the required value into a variable (say id) so, later you can use the variable name to substituue the value wherever it has been sent. Please search Google for Jmeter Correlation, you will find many links to accomplish.

Comment: That sounds good and would probably work in most cases. Unfortunately in my setup, the data that exists in those fields is not text. It's this setup where you start typing and it provides a list of selections based on your input. When you click one, it turns into a sort of button. Within the HTML, there is simply a "<span class='selected choice></span>" with no real indicator as to what it is. I think pulling the data from the page is a no-go. I figured it would be. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: There are only two sources of data. If client generates (using js etc.) data, then use Parameterization. If server sends the data to client then use Correlation. So, our job is to find what is the source of data and use either parameterization (provide multiple values using CSV) or Correlation (use regular expression extractor).  hope it helps.